# Не устанавливаются параметры для Checkbutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Недавно открыл для себя Python, в частности библиотеку Tkinter. Добрались руки до `Checkbutton`.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import Checkbutton

window=Tk()
window.geometry('100x100')
window["bg"]="grey25"

Flip_forward_state = BooleanVar()
Flip_forward_state.set(True)
Flip_forward = Checkbutton(window, text='Сделать кувырок вперёд',font=("consolas", 15), bg="grey25", fg="white", var=Flip_forward_state)
Flip_forward.place(x=0, y=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Пытаюсь задать параметры `bg`, `font`, `fg`и выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\tester.py", line 10, in <module>
    Flip_forward = Checkbutton(window, text='Сделать кувырок вперёд',font=("consolas", 15), bg="grey25", fg="white", var=Flip_forward_state)
  File "C:\Users\apaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 630, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::checkbutton", kw)
  File "C:\Users\apaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 552, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\apaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font"
```

Прошу помощи, никак не могу понять в чём проблема. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы импортируете `Checkbutton` из `tkinter.ttk`, а `font` поддерживается только в `tkinter`. Воспользуйтесь аналогичным виджетом из `tkinter`:

```
from tkinter import Checkbutton
```